# data type for the date as 16-Apr-82 in mssql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

what datatype should be used with the input date as 16-Apr-82 in mssql?the table demands that the date be inputted as 16-Apr-82.

Comment: It is unclear what you are after. Could you clarify? 

Who is demanding what? 

Does the date have to be stored this way, or is it enough if it can be retrieved this way? 

Also important: Are you ever going to access rows by either Filtering or sorting on this date column? 

And finally, and this is general  advice for asking questions, but particularly important for Stackoverflow, tell us what you have tried so far and why it does not meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You can user Varchar(11) to store date see below format for date-

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),getdate(), 106), ' ', '-'))
```

However it is recommended to use default  SQL date datatype.